# Restricting Azure Infrastructure Permissions

Tags: azure

I have an Azure subscription where users need to be granted access at the resource group level so they can create new resources.  However I need to restrict the actions they can perform.  They need to be able to create VMs in their resource group, but not vNets.  (What we are trying to accomplish is restrict them from creating vNets to prevent creating new entry points into the environment).

What is the best method to allow permissions be granted at the resource group level to perform "safe" actions (create VM) but restrict "unsafe" actions (create vNet w public IP)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Azure Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) enables fine-grained access management for Azure. Using RBAC, you can grant only the amount of access that users need to perform their jobs. This article helps you get up and running with RBAC in the Azure portal. If you want more details about how RBAC helps you manage access, see What is Role-Based Access Control: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-what-is

Azure RBAC has three basic roles that apply to all resource types:

Owner has full access to all resources including the right to delegate access to others.
Contributor can create and manage all types of Azure resources but can’t grant access to others.
Reader can view existing Azure resources.

Reference:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-what-is#built-in-roles

Create a custom role in Azure Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) if none of the built-in roles meet your specific access needs. Reference:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-custom-roles